# How to make a jQuery DataTable readonly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery datatable which is setup as below. I made it editable in the document.ready function. I am trying to control the Add/Delete/Update functions based on the role of the currently logged in user. I am able to do this for Add/Delete operations by adding disabled attribute for these two buttons. In the document.ready function, I have a function EnableUserAddDeleteButtons() which will check the role of the user and enable the buttons by removing the attribute "disabled" if it is an authorized user. But I am not sure how to make all the cells read-only when the user is not authorized. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UserDataTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    }).makeEditable({
        "aoColumns": [{}, {}, {}, {},
        {
            type: 'select',
            onblur: 'submit',
            data: "{'True':'True', 'False':'False'}"
        },
        {
            type: 'select',
            onblur: 'submit',
            data: "{'True':'True', 'False':'False'}"
        },
        {
            type: 'select',
            onblur: 'submit',
            data: "{'True':'True', 'False':'False'}"
        }],

        sUpdateURL: "/Admin/UpdateUser"
        sAddURL: "/Admin/InsertUser"
        sDeleteURL: "/Admin/DeleteUser"

        sAddNewRowFormId: "formAddNewUser",
        sAddNewRowButtonId: "btnAddNewUser",
        sAddNewRowOkButtonId: "btnAdd",
        sAddNewRowCancelButtonId: "btnCancel",
        sDeleteRowButtonId: "btnDeleteUser",

        fnShowError: function (message, action) {
            switch (action) {
                case "update":
                    jAlert(message, "Update failed");
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    jAlert(message, "Delete failed");
                    break;
                case "add":
                    $("#lblAddError").html(message);
                    $("#lblAddError").show();
                    break;
            }
        },
        fnStartProcessingMode: function () {
            $("#processing_message").dialog();
        },
        fnEndProcessingMode: function () {
            $("#processing_message").dialog("close");
        }
    });

    EnableUserAddDeleteButtons();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Just remember to do that same validation on the server-side when sending the data back from the client, as it'd be trivial to re-enable the functionality.